# Shadow to the left, right and the bottom

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using this code:

```
border-right:0px solid #ddd;
height:85px;    
box-shadow :5px 5px 10px 1px #eaeaea;
```

but i just got this results http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpmPYq

I want to add the same width with shadow at left, buttom and the right side

I'll add this shadow to the dropdown menu at this site http://94.247.169.169/~welloteket/

Answer (score 1):

If you want all four sides shadowed, try this following **code:**

```
div {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 100px #000;
box-shadow: 0 0 100px #000;
}
```

I tested this on CodePen aswell, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RpVeRG, It is because your Y and X is offset.

If you are looking for the left, right and bottom to be shadowed.

**You can use the following code instead:**

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(100,100,100);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(100,100,100);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(100,100,100);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ppmxoa

Comment: Hmm, now it gets shadows over the full box. I just want shadow at left, right and buttom :-/

Comment: If you check at Nelly.se - the dropdown style they have is great, i am trying the same but i cant figure that out.

Comment: @borresnorre I have just updated my answer, try the second option out :) It should work mate !

Comment: I am trying this but it still get shadows at the top. Please check this URL and check: http://94.247.169.169/~welloteket/

Comment: @borresnorre Updated it again, incremented the pixel, try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpjYwW

Comment: Now its great, but i want other color at the shadow. Like nelly.se - how do i change the opacity at the #000 color? I am newbie so i am trying to learn :)

Comment: Perfect, can u make more width at the shadow at this side? http://prntscr.com/ej0ifw

Comment: @borresnorre, Not doing anymore of your work, you can find that out for yourself.

Comment: I was just added this code: .nav-dropdown {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 100px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #eaeaea;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #eaeaea;
box-shadow: 0px 9px 8px #eaeaea;
} - but the results is http://94.247.169.169/~welloteket/ - looks very funny :P

Comment: @borresnorre, haha just change the colors around then !

Comment: Ahh, i fixed it. Thank u very much @leon

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```css
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    border-right: 0px solid #ddd;
    height: 85px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px 1px #eaeaea, -5px 5px 10px #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This code work well, but now its shadow at the top again: http://prntscr.com/eizu6r you can go and check the url by here: http://94.247.169.169/~welloteket/ - this stuffs makes me crazy :D

Comment: Try this code : .nav-dropdown {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), -5px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

Comment: The code is added, but it still looks like shadow at the top: http://prntscr.com/ej08vr

Comment: No.it's not shadow..."header-bottom" background color is #FCF9F9 and "nav-dropdown" background color is #FFFFFF. for different background color, it looks like shadow.if you change "header-bottom" background color to "#FFFFFF". You will get no shadow.